# Get Random Product

Tags: magento-1.9

How to get Random Product here? It always show first 5 product i want to show random product

```
<div class="Seller-other-product">

<?php $active = Mage::getStoreConfig('marketplace/admin_approval_seller_registration/displayproductpage');
    if ($active == 1) { 

    $sellerId      = Mage::registry('current_product')->getSellerId();

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller_id',$sellerId);
    $collection->addStoreFilter();




    }

 ?>
<?php //echo $sellerId->getStoreTitle();?>
 <h1> Other Collection Of This Seller </h1>

<div class="seller-products">
                    <ul id = "seller-product-list1" class="sell-block">
                    <?php 
                        if (count($collection) > 0) {
                            $a = 1;
                                foreach($collection as $product){ ?>
                                <?php if($a%6==0) 
                                { 
                                    break;
                                }?>
                                <li class="item<?php if($a==1):endif;?>">
                                    <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl(); ?>">
                                        <img class="product-image1" 
                                            <?php if($a==1):?>
                                                src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200,280); ?>" 

                                            <?php else:?>
                                                src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(200,280); ?>" 
                                            <?php endif;?>
                                                alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
                                                <?php //echo $product->getName() ;?>


                                                <p class="product-name"><a title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($product->getName()) ?>" href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>">  
                                    <?php 
                                    if (strlen($product->getName()) > 25) :
                                      echo strip_tags(substr($product->getName(), 0, 15)).'...';
                                    else : 
                                      echo $product->getName();
                                    endif;
                                  ?>
                                  </a>
                                                <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($product); ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php $a++;}
                    }?>
                </ul>

            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help with display random products code](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33388/need-help-with-display-random-products-code)

Comment: @fschmengler Check my question Both are Different

Comment: But it comes down to the same solution if you understand it.

Comment: I don't think same Ok i will check it

Answer (score 1):

I got Answer For this

I used `rand()` Function

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*'); //add product attribute to be fetched
    $collection->getSelect()->order('rand()');//get random product
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('seller_id',$sellerId);
    $collection->addStoreFilter();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your collection to Randomize the results and limit to 1 in the results set

$_productCollection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));

Comment: Although this would work it is worth noting that ordering a query randomly means the query can no longer be cached.

Comment: And hence has a potential performance impact - Kothari didnt give any information as to the query size to judge so I plumped for the quickest/least work implementation

Comment: Sorry i am not getting